# Element that is fixed at bottom of browser until it hits the bottom of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The website I'm working on making some stylistic differences on is https://www.crunchydata.com/. There's a div with id #bottom that's currently fixed at the bottom of the viewport until you hit the bottom of the page.

What I'd like to do is have it be fixed at the bottom of the viewport until it reaches the bottom of the div #main-content (right before the footer), and then sit there at the bottom of #main-content as the user scrolls past into the footer until the user scrolls back up.

I'm assuming this will require some sort of JavaScript solution, but haven't been able to find any solution quite close enough to what I'm looking for. Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want that: position of #bottom will be fixed until user scroll at the bottom of the #content section. Then, when user scroll under #content then the position of the #bottom will be relative?

Comment: look for position:sticky and polyfills that goes with it ...

Comment: @JituRaiyan, yes, that's exactly what I'm looking for!

Comment: Ok, I'll try to solve this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add this JavaScript code. It works fine in all devices (any device width or height):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 var scrollPoint;

 $(window).on('load resize scroll', function(){

 scrollPoint = $("#footer").position().top - $(window).height() + $("#bottom").outerHeight();

 if($(window).scrollTop() > scrollPoint){
  $('#bottom').css({
   'position' : 'relative',
   'top' : 0,
   'bottom' : ''
  });
 }else{
  $('#bottom').css({
   'position' : 'fixed',
   'top' : '',
   'bottom' : 0
  });
 }
 });
});
```

And it's working very fine and there is no hard code. Here is the output:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This works really well - is there any way you'd recommend adding a smooth transition between the fixed and relative positions? Adding just a regular "transition all" doesn't look too great it seems

Comment: I just updated my code. You need to assigning the value of bottomPos and  scrollPoint inside the event. Otherwise, It does not work onresize properly.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to animate between position: fixed and relative.

Comment: If you slow down the scrolling, the #bottom element starts jumping pixels pretty badly. Any idea what would cause this?

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that. There is no logical error for this type of bug. But, unfortunately it happens. So, I need to find out alternative way to solve this question.

Comment: OK - please let me know if you find anything & I'll continue looking as well.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to look into using position:sticky.  If you're still looking for a pure JS solution, you can simply check how far down the page the user has scrolled, and if it is far enough, "lock" the element to the page.

Example:

```js
document.body.onscroll=function(){
  var bottom=document.getElementById("bottom");
  if(scrollY+innerHeight>1050){ //position of where you want the element to go + it's height
    bottom.style.position="absolute";
    bottom.style.top="1000px";
    bottom.style.bottom="";
  }
  else{
    bottom.style.position="fixed";
    bottom.style.bottom="0px";
    bottom.style.top="";
  }
}
```

```css
#bottom{
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0px;
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div style="height:1000px;width:100%;background-color:red;"></div>
<div style="height:1000px;width:100%;background-color:yellow;"></div>
<div id="bottom"></div>
```

A bit messy, but gets the job done.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vwgzmdk5/)

Comment: Thanks! This is perfect!

Comment: Position:sticky also doesn't have great support across different browsers (notably IE there's none at all). So thank you for helping find a JavaScript answer

Answer (score 1):

This is working. Please check.

```js
document.body.onscroll=function(){
    var bottom=document.getElementById("bottom");
    if(scrollY+innerHeight>1050){ //position of where you want the element to go + it's height
        bottom.style.position="relative";
        bottom.style.top="1000px";
        bottom.style.bottom="";
    }
    else{
        bottom.style.position="fixed";
        bottom.style.bottom="0px";
        bottom.style.top="";
    }
 }
```

```css
#bottom{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div style="height:1000px;width:100%;background-color:red;">
<div id="bottom" style="width:100%;height:50px;background-color:blue"></div>
</div>
<div style="height:1000px;width:100%;background-color:yellow;"></div>
```

Comment: At the expense of sounding petty, this would appear to be an exact duplicate of my answer...could you explain your intent?

Comment: I have edited the positon in js and changed the code in html. I have checked your snippet and it was not working.

Comment: Oh...my apologies, I see what you're saying.  They appear to be functioning more-or-less the same on my end, though?

Comment: When I checked your code snippet it was not working so by editing your code it worked.

Comment: @dav you went about it beautifully, and props to Nimish for the correction too.